# EFK stack JSON log not being shown

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, efk

I have deployed an EFK stack in a Kubernetes cluster.

I have configured it in a way where fluentd will fetch Nginx logs as well as PHP logs( both are in JSON format and both are one JSON log per line ).

This is my config:

```
fluent.conf: |-
    @include custom.conf
    @include conf.d/*.conf

    <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        @id out_es
        @log_level info
        include_tag_key true
        host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
        port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
        path "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PATH']}"
        scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
        ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
        ssl_version "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERSION'] || 'TLSv1'}"
        reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'false'}"
        reconnect_on_error "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RECONNECT_ON_ERROR'] || 'true'}"
        reload_on_failure "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_ON_FAILURE'] || 'true'}"
        log_es_400_reason "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOG_ES_400_REASON'] || 'false'}"
        logstash_prefix "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_PREFIX'] || 'logstash'}"
        logstash_format "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_FORMAT'] || 'true'}"
        index_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_INDEX_NAME'] || 'logstash'}"
        type_name "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_TYPE_NAME'] || 'fluentd'}"
        <buffer>
            flush_thread_count "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_THREAD_COUNT'] || '8'}"
            flush_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_FLUSH_INTERVAL'] || '5s'}"
            chunk_limit_size "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_CHUNK_LIMIT_SIZE'] || '2M'}"
            queue_limit_length "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_QUEUE_LIMIT_LENGTH'] || '32'}"
            retry_max_interval "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_BUFFER_RETRY_MAX_INTERVAL'] || '30'}"
            retry_forever true
        </buffer>
    </match>
```

```
custom.conf: |
    <match fluent.**>
        @type null
    </match>
    <source>
      @type tail
      read_from_head true
      tag kubernetes.*
      path /var/log/k8s/*/*/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/k8s/customcontainerlogs.log.pos
      format json
      <parse>
        @type json
        json_parser oj
        time_type string
        time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
      </parse>
    </source>
```

Essentially I am trying to get all logs and stream them.

Using the abovementioned config I can only get the nginx logs for some reason, each one looking like:

```json
{
  "_index": "logstash-2021.04.24",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "kJMpBXkBcnb7LiWny-tT",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "request": "GET / HTTP/1.1",
    "http_referer": "",
    "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36",
    "time_iso8601": "2021-04-24T18:34:50+00:00",
    "status": "404",
    "request_time": "0.004",
    "header_access_id": "",
    "ip": "10.200.11.106",
    "@timestamp": "2021-04-24T18:34:50.708281784+00:00",
    "tag": "kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.nginx.api-access.log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "time_iso8601": [
      "2021-04-24T18:34:50.000Z"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-04-24T18:34:50.708Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1619289290708
  ]
}
```

If I add `@type none` in the parse section:

```
<parse>
    @type json
    @type none
    time_type string
    time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
</parse>
```

I can see 2 logs every time I hit refresh (404 from Nginx and PHP error log No route found) but they are not formatted... it's all in the message as a string:

Example for a PHP log:

```json
{
  "_index": "logstash-2021.04.24",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "13QsBXkBuBa2uOG0PQSr",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "{\"email\":\"\",\"channel\":\"api_error_channel\",\"level\":\"WARNING\",\"message\":\"No route found\",\"backtrace\":[\"[Library\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Exception\\\\RouterListenerException] \\/app\\/Api\\/Data\\/bootstrap.php.cache:21384\",\"Library\\\\HttpKernel\\\\EventListener\\\\RouterListener->onKernelRoute\",\"->call_user_func\",\"Library\\\\EventDispatcher\\\\EventDispatcher->doDispatch\",\"Library\\\\EventDispatcher\\\\EventDispatcher->dispatch\",\"Library\\\\HttpKernel\\\\HttpKernel->handleRaw\",\"Library\\\\HttpKernel\\\\HttpKernel->handle\"],\"request\":{\"id\":\"210850ea-a52c-11eb-820b-f66ccf92cc93\",\"date\":\"2021-04-24 18:37:31\",\"path\":\"\\/\"},\"response\":{\"status_code\":404,\"body\":{\"Error\":{\"Code\":100004,\"Message\":\"Invalid route\"}}}}",
    "@timestamp": "2021-04-24T18:37:31.688259336+00:00",
    "tag": "kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.php.api_error.log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-04-24T18:37:31.688Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1619289451688
  ]
}
```

```
2021-04-26 14:30:36 +0000 [info]: parsing config file is succeeded path="/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf"
2021-04-26 14:30:36 +0000 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <match fluent.**>
    @type null
  </match>
  <source>
    @type tail
    read_from_head true
    tag "kubernetes.*"
    path "/var/log/k8s/*/*/*.log"
    pos_file "/var/log/k8s/innercontainerlogs.log.pos"
    <parse>
      @type "json"
    </parse>
  </source>
  <match **>
    @type elasticsearch
    @id out_es
    @log_level "debug"
    include_tag_key true
    host "elasticsearch.monitoring.svc.cluster.local"
    port 9200
    path ""
    scheme http
    ssl_verify true
    ssl_version TLSv1
    reload_connections false
    reconnect_on_error true
    reload_on_failure true
    log_es_400_reason false
    logstash_prefix "logstash"
    logstash_format true
    index_name "logstash"
    type_name "fluentd"
    <buffer>
      flush_thread_count 8
      flush_interval 5s
      chunk_limit_size 2M
      queue_limit_length 32
      retry_max_interval 30
      retry_forever true
    </buffer>
  </match>
</ROOT>
2021-04-26 14:30:36 +0000 [info]: starting fluentd-1.4.2 pid=7 ruby="2.6.3"
2021-04-26 14:30:36 +0000 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/usr/local/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/fluentd", "-c", "/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf", "-p", "/fluentd/plugins", "--gemfile", "/fluentd/Gemfile", "--under-supervisor"]
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-concat' version '2.3.0'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '3.4.3'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-grok-parser' version '2.5.1'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-json-in-json-2' version '1.0.2'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter' version '2.1.6'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser' version '1.0.0'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-prometheus' version '1.3.0'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '2.1.1'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-systemd' version '1.0.2'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '1.4.2'
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="fluent.**" type="null"
2021-04-26 14:30:38 +0000 [info]: adding match pattern="**" type="elasticsearch"
2021-04-26 14:30:42 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2021-04-26 14:30:46 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2021-04-26 14:30:54 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2021-04-26 14:31:10 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Detected ES 7.x or above: `_doc` will be used as the document `_type`.
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: adding source type="tail"
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=10 ppid=7 worker=0
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] buffer started instance=70277432939320 stage_size=0 queue_size=0
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] flush_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [debug]: #0 [out_es] enqueue_thread actually running
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/k8s/api/nginx/api-access.log
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/k8s/api/nginx/api-error.log
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/k8s/api/nginx/error.log
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/k8s/api/nginx/access.log
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 following tail of /var/log/k8s/api/php/api_error.log
2021-04-26 14:31:42 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0
```

What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT #1:**

I checked the error logs and I am getting this:

```
2021-04-25 16:44:35 +0000 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Parser::ParserError error="pattern not match with data 'No route found'" location=nil tag="kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.php.api_error.log" time=2021-04-25 16:44:35.639766416 +0000 record={"email"=>"", "channel"=>"api_error_channel", "level"=>"WARNING", "message"=>"No route found", "backtrace"=>["[Library\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\RouterListenerException] /app/Api/Data/bootstrap.php.cache:21384", "Library\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener->onKernelRoute", "->call_user_func", "Library\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->doDispatch", "Library\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->dispatch", "Library\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw", "Library\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle"], "request"=>{"id"=>"84a434e8-a5e5-11eb-b41b-c629ad91f8c7", "date"=>"2021-04-25 16:44:35", "path"=>"/"}, "response"=>{"status_code"=>404, "body"=>{"Error"=>{"Code"=>100004, "Message"=>"Invalid route"}}}}
```

**EDIT #2:**

I ran the raw JSON log through a validator and it's a valid JSON.

**EDIT #3:**

Added startup logs

**EDIT #4:**
This is an example of debug stdout logs:

```
2021-04-27 09:22:42.429274874 +0000 kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.php.api_error.log: {"email":"","channel":"api_error_channel","level":"WARNING","message":"No route found","backtrace":["[Library\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\RouterListenerException] /app/Api/Data/bootstrap.php.cache:21384","Library\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener->onKernelRoute","->call_user_func","Library\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->doDispatch","Library\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher->dispatch","Library\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handleRaw","Library\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel->handle"],"request":{"id":"1e5ce058-a73a-11eb-9e48-1e539c74b43b","date":"2021-04-27 09:22:42","path":"/"},"response":{"status_code":404,"body":{"Error":{"Code":100004,"Message":"Invalid route"}}},"tag":"kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.php.api_error.log"}
2021-04-27 09:22:37.854071485 +0000 kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.nginx.api-access.log: {"request":"GET / HTTP/1.1","http_referer":"","http_user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36","time_iso8601":"2021-04-27T09:22:37+00:00","status":"404","request_time":"0.004","header_access_id":"","ip":"10.200.11.106","tag":"kubernetes.var.log.k8s.api.nginx.api-access.log"}
```

Comment: Did you try to run `fluentd` in debug mode and look at its logs?

Comment: I got an error, updated the question

Comment: Add the startup logs as well including the config dump.

Comment: Are you putting both `@type json` and `@type none` at the same time in `<parse>` section?

Comment: No i am not. I was using none to overwrite json temporarily. Also I cleaned up the config a bit. Is it possible that the reason I am not getting both logs is because the nginx logs and the php logs are in a different format? Even more, the php logs can have multiple formats. All the logs are json encoded tho

Comment: Right. You should test with `log_level debug`, `logstash_format false`, and route `fluentd.**` and `tail` to `stdout`. For testing, you can simply turn off `elasticsearch` output plugin and route logs only to `stdout`, just to make sure that you're getting the correct logs. After that, you can test with `elasticsearch`.

Comment: Will do! Thank you for the tips! I'll post my findings

Comment: Added the debug logs. They all seem to be correct

Comment: 2021-04-26 14:30:42 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_es] Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. Connection refused - connect(2) for 10.109.189.187:9200 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Comment: Where is your `elasticsearch` deployed?

Comment: This was because the cluster was starting up. You can ignore them

Comment: Right. Try with `logstash_format false` and parser `@type none` in debug mode. Look for errors in the logs also.

Comment: Also, I'm seeing `scheme http` along with `ssl_verify true` and `ssl_version TLSv1`. I'm not sure if that's intentional. If SSL is required then the `scheme` should be `https`.

Comment: Not intentional, im using http, removed the ssl options, still the same. Also if i set the @type to none then i am getting all the logs, but if it's set to json i noticed that each time i reindex i get different results. I get only api logs or nginx logs on each reindex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231648/discussion-between-stefantigro-and-azeem).